# How can I generate a smaller HDF5 file?

Tags: deep-learning, hdf5

I am working on an image classification problem with a dataset of about 1,000,000 images summing up to a total size of ~36 GB. I am trying to train a CNN model with this data on a machine with 256GB RAM (and 4 x 16GB VRAM).

To solve the memory issues that I was facing with directly feeding the images to the program, I tried converting the raw image data to HDF5 format. However, the size of the HDF5 file kept growing and the converter crashed when it ran out of disk space. The HDF5 file sitting on the disk is at 2.2TB!!

Is this size expected? How can I convert this to a (preferably much) smaller file?

Comment: Using HDF5 won't solve memory issues by itself, you just need to use something like a generator to load only a batch of images into memory from disk, which should not run into any memory issues. What exact framework are you using?

Comment: I am using h5py to convert the data into an HDF5 file and keras' ImageDataGenerator class to load the data

Comment: ImageDataGenerator can load the data directly from disk (with flow_from_directory), you don't need an HDF5 file for this

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I read that ImageDataGenerator induces a lot of i/o in the pipeline which makes reading image data very slow. Hence the HDF5 conversion

Comment: You don't really have a choice, it is either reading 36 GB of data, or more than 2.2TB, which do you think its better?

Comment: I was looking for a confirmation that indeed a ~36 GB video file translates into a 2.2TB HDF5 file. If that's true, I guess I will go with reading 36 GB of data

Comment: If you uncompress the images, then surely it will be too much data. We don't have code that shows how you are making the HDF5, so we can just assume your HDF5 isn't compressed.